# Nginx - Use different directory for serving files while stripping out path from URL

Tags: nginx

I am trying to use different directory from where to serve the files, but have been unsuccessful. `/var/www/site.app/public` is where the root, but I want to serve `news` from `/var/www/news/api` instead, while having URL `http://site.app/news/123`, from which I want to remove the `news` part, because otherwise it would map to `/var/www/news/api/news/123`.

Judging by the debug logs, it seems that it gets rewritten correctly when first testing all location blocks, but after it is done rewritting, it goes through all of them again, and ends up serving content with location block `/`.

Here is my configuration file I have.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.app;
    root /var/www/site.app/public;

    rewrite_log on;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /news/ {
        root /var/www/news/api;
        rewrite ^/news/(.*) /api.php?_=$1;
        index index.php index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `root` directive in your `/news/` location currently does nothing. You are rewriting the URI to `/api.php` which then hits your `\.(hh|php)$` location, which inherits the `root` from the parent server container.

You need a distinct location for `/api.php`, possibly `/news/api.php`. In which case you can construct a separate location block (possibly nested within `/news/`) where you can place `fastcgi_pass` code using the different root.

Comment: About first part: so does that mean it is intentional that Nginx goes through location directives again after rewriting the request URI? About second part: couldn't I just use `try_files` with exact full path to api.php? Instead of having multiple location directives.

Comment: @ncla 1) Yes - but it can be controlled with flags. 2) Even if `try_files` rewrites the URI, you still need a location to process it as a `fastcgi_pass` with the appropriate parameters and/or root.

Comment: So I managed to get it to work, I have `/match/` location directive with rewrite only, and then another location directive for `= /api.php`, where I define `root` and `try_files` to `api.php`, and added PHP stuff to the location directive (didn't have to change fastcgi_pass or anything). Though this `api.php` does not seem like a good solution and feels dirty, is there anything to improve?

Comment: URLs like this `http://site.app/api.php?6758` will allow access to it, which isn't kinda desirable.

Comment: I deny access to that kind of URL with `if($request_uri !~ ^/match/) { return 444; }`. Is there any security concerns with this?

Answer (score 0):

So this is not ideal solution, but it works. By default it would still allow access to api.php, but I am denying access to it by checking if the URL contains `/news/`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.app;
    root /var/www/site.app/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /api.php {
        if ($request_uri !~ ^/news/) {
            return 444;
        }

        root /var/www/site.app/news/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /api.php?$query_string =408;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /news/ {
        rewrite ^/news/(.*) /api.php?$1;
    }

    location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =407;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```